# Select files with recursive glob for babel command

Tags: node.js, unix, babeljs

Given the following folder structure:

```
.
└── dogs
    ├── index.js
    └── cats
        ├── index.js
        └── racoons
            ├── index.js
            └── walrus
                └── index.js
```

I'd like to run the babel-cli command `babel` and generate files corresponding to each `index.js` as `index.build.js`.

The babel command takes in a file or folder as such:

```
babel index.js --out-file index.build.js
```

And I am wondering it it can take a recursive glob.

Answer (score 0):

You could process all the `index.js` files in the current directory (and subdirectories) with:

```
babel . --only index.js -d /output/directory
```

this would duplicate the sub-folder structure of the current directory in `/output/directory` and place the compiled files there.

Also, one could delegate the processing to bash and execute babel on each file independently:

```
function processFile(){
    local fPath=$1
    local fDir=$(dirname $fPath)
    local fName=$(basename $fPath)

    pushd "$fDir"
    babel "$fName" -o "${fName%.js}.build.js"
    popd
}
export -f processFile

find . -type f -name "index.js" -exec bash -c 'processFile "$0"' {} \;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I am looking for a way to not have an output directory.